# EF4 model referencing through result foreign keys using linq to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Using one big EF4 model I'm trying to do some of the same things, that can be done in linq2sql using separate dbml's. A basic issue I have run into, which is likely a very fundamental lack of knowledge of linq to entities on my behalf, is how do you use result references to find objects in tables that are referenced?

Example, I have 4 tables that are all linked together through foreign keys.

Conceptually I can hop through all of the tables using foreach on the result references, however it seems pretty clumsy, how could below code be written using linq instead?

```
            //Get book
            var book= db.books.SingleOrDefault(d => d.bookId == 286);

            //If no book, return
            if (book == null) return null;

            //Get the shelf associated with this book
            List<shelf> slist = new List<shelf>();

            foreach (reading r in book.readings)
            { 
                foreach (event re in r.events)
                {
                    slist.Add(re);
                }
            }
            List<event> bookevents = slist.Distinct().ToList();

            //Get the customers associated with the events
            List<int> clist = new List<int>();

            foreach (event eb in bookevents)
            {
                var cust = db.customers.Where(c => c.customerID == eb.inID || c.customerID == eb.outID).ToList();
                clist.AddRange(cust.Select(c => c.customerID));
            }

            //Return the list of customers
            return clist;
```

EDIT:
I got it down to 3 steps, posting this in case other people run into similar issues. I welcome any comments on how to do this more elegantly

```
        //Get book
        var book= db.books.SingleOrDefault(d => d.bookId == 286);

        //If no book, return
        if (book == null) return null;

        //Get the bookevents associated with this book
        var bookevents = (from reading in book.readings
                   select reading.events).SelectMany(e => e).Distinct();

        //Get the customers associated with the events
        var clist = (from be in bookevents
                    from c in db.customers
                    where c.customerID == be.inID || c.customerID == be.outID
                    select c.customerID).ToList();

        //Return the list of customers
        return clist;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var distinctEvents = (from event in db.events
               join reading in db.readings on event.readingID equals reading.readingID
               where reading.bookID == 286
               select event).Distinct();
               // if you want to see this bookID is present in Book table, you should add a join statement like "join book in db.books on reading.bookID == book.bookID"
var custIdList = from c in db.customers
                 from event in distinctsEvents
                 where c.customerID == event.inID || c.customerID == be.outID
                 select c.customerID;

return custIdList.ToList();
```

Comment: No problem, tell me if you need more hints. and if this worked for you, you may mark it as answer.